# Where are the docker Remote API logs stored?

Tags: docker, docker-api

I have Docker on OpenSuse Leap 42.1. I have setup Remote API. Where can I see the logs/STDOUT of the Remote API service? Specifically the logs indicating API calls such as GET and POST calls.

I checked the docker service logs using:

`journalctl -u docker.service`

But this only indicates that API is listening on a port. Doesn't actually show the information about the calls being made.

`time="2016-10-31T17:44:07.170795338Z" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"`

When I ran the docker deamon directly I was able to see the REST API information in the STDOUT. I am guessing it is not storing STDOUT to logs.

Comment: Have you checked `docker logs <container id>`?

Comment: @Rao docker logs provide me with logs of the container. I am interested in logs of the Docker Service itself and not of a specific container.

Answer (score 0):

I have Docker Engine 1.13.1 on CentOS 7.3.1611.

I added dockerd option.

```
/usr/bin/dockerd --log-level=debug (...snip...)
```

I found API log in journalctl.

```
Feb 15 10:12:52 xxx dockerd[7596]: time="2017-02-15T10:12:52.456651320+09:00" level=debug msg="Calling POST /containers/create"
Feb 15 10:12:52 xxx dockerd[7596]: time="2017-02-15T10:12:52.456886794+09:00" level=debug msg="form data: {\"AttachStdin\":true,...
```